# Unix/Linux comma deliminated files

Tags: linux

I have comma deliminated file that basically has the structure of:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,,,, 6, etc

I have to count the number of unique 6th columns.  Pleasseee help

(btw this is an intro to unix/linux class so this should be able to be done with basic commands)

Comment: I am concerned of the quality of coming generation sw developer quality. I don't think I should solve your assignment. That was point 1. Point 2 is that this is SO. What have you tried so far? What was the result? So: My advice to you is to study these basic unix  commands and learn. The purpose of the exercise is that YOU learn and get a feeling for how they work - by trial and error if nothing else.

Comment: This was a part of an assignment that the instructor guided us through (ie. this was something that he didnt think we could do without his help thus far in the class), however I didn't save the file with the answer when I thought I did.  We are in a fairly introductory class, so we are just learning the different commands and how they work.  From what we learned in class the prior few days I believe it would have to do with regular expressions (possibly combined with grep and wc).  In this situation the previous 1,2,3.. etc were actually strings and we had to find the amount of unique #6

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation.  I have tried a number of combinations of grep and wc however I believe I am using the wrong syntax with everthing, so I am getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cut -d "," -f 6 myFile |sort |uniq -c |wc -l`

Comment: Again, sorry for the lack of explanation, but this is a little farther than we have gotten.  I explained basically where we are at and what we have learned in the comments under the original question

Comment: Did you even try the given solution? You don't need regex for that. And unless the strings contain commas themselves, the solution works for strings and does exactly what you want.

Comment: yes this does work, however I was hoping you could help me with a solution dealing with what has been covered in this course as that is what would help me in the test

Comment: This doesn't count the number of distinct entries.  For that, append `| wc -l`

Comment: Indeed, I misread the question. Thought he wants the amount of each distinct entry. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into my crystal ball, I see that your class is discussing `awk`.  Try

```
awk -F, '!a[$6]++{c++} END{ print c }' input-file
```